# SQL code need help understanding

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a movie database and I thought it might be a good idea to have some type of parental control in place for the future. I wrote some SQL code and it works for the most part, but i don't know why.

In my main movies table I have movies rated with the standard rating g, pg, pg-13, r, and NC-17.

Here is the SQL code i used

```
Select title
From movies
Where rating < "r";
```

I works though it still shows the NC-17 shows. If I change the r rating to NC-17 it only shows the g rated shows.

I know I can type out a longer SQL to give me the matches I want, but I want to understand why this code is performing the way it is.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: "But I want to understand why this code is performing the way it is."  Look at the ascii numerical value for the first character in each of your strings.  It may help you understand. http://www.asciitable.com/  NC-17 < g because ascii code 78 (N) is < 103 (g).  For string compares such as this the ascii numeric code is used to evaluate < or > .  +1 for a reasonable question about inner workings of something.

Comment: Everyone thank you for the explanation and other solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL doesn't understand the movie rating system.  The `<` operator looks at strings in alphabetical order.  So when you say `< 'R'`, it's looking for for all ratings that start with a letter before `R` in the alphabet.  Since there are a limited number of options for ratings, you're best off doing something along the lines of this:

```
SELECT title
FROM movies
WHERE rating NOT LIKE 'R'
AND   rating NOT LIKE 'NC-17'
```

Answer (score 4):

How is MySQL to know `R` is less than `NC-17`? MySQL knows how to sort numbers and letters but not movie ratings. You have to assign the ratings numbers and sort based on that.

For example:

```
Rating    Value
------------------
  G         1
  PG        10
  PG-13     20
  R         30
  NC-17     40
```

Than give each movie the numerical value of the rating (or use a join) and then sort on *that*.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query that would probably work for you if you want to rank them:

```
SELECT m.title, m.rating
FROM 
(
  SELECT s.title, s.rating, 
         CASE WHEN s.rating = 'G' THEN 1 
              WHEN s.rating = 'PG' THEN 2
              WHEN s.rating = 'PG-13' THEN 3
              WHEN s.rating = 'R' THEN 4
              WHEN s.rating = 'NC-17' THEN 5
              ELSE 6 END AS MovieRanking
  FROM movies s
) m
WHERE m.MovieRanking < 4
```